# unable to locate element in selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, stack, chromium

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager


# Initiate the browser
browser  = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

# Open the Website
browser.get("https://lpsc.codetantra.com/login.jsp")

codetantra_name="JE7-202@lpsc-ab.com"
codetantra_password="AB0707"

browser.find_element_by_name("loginId").send_keys(codetantra_name)

browser.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys(codetantra_password)

browser.find_element_by_class_name("pull-right").click()

browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='homeCenterDiv']/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/a").click()
```

Comment: Your answer does not show the code in a suitable format, please modify it so that it is easier for other users to read.

In addition to being clear, it must say where the error occurs, the error message, and what options you have previously tried.

In this case it may be helpful to know the html content of your web page

Comment: Please help fast it is showing no such element found

Comment: error:Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='homeCenterDiv']/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/a"}
  (Session info: chrome=90.0.4430.212)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to introduce webdriverwait to get this job done. the element that you wanna click is a text node. it is not a normal text though.
Check out the below code :

**Code :**

```
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\Inc\\Desktop\\Selenium+Python\\chromedriver.exe")
    driver.maximize_window()
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
    driver.get('https://lpsc.codetantra.com/login.jsp')
    codetantra_name="JE7-202@lpsc-ab.com"
    codetantra_password="AB0707"
    
    driver.find_element_by_name("loginId").send_keys(codetantra_name)
    
    driver.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys(codetantra_password)
    
    driver.find_element_by_id("loginBtn").click()
    
    button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[role='button'][title='Click here to view Meetings']")))
    button.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a wait condition / delay before locating the element.
Add this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "loginId"))).click()
```

After that you can normally fill the password and click the login button

Comment: Hey its not working ,i have already tried it!  I am talking about this one:     browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='homeCenterDiv']/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/a").click()

Comment: What exactly not working?

Comment: the webdriver delay is not working

Comment: When something not working it normally presents some error, not saying "I'm not working"

Comment: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"https://lpsc.codetantra.com/secure/tla/m.jsp"}
  (Session info: chrome=90.0.4430.212)    It is giving this error don't be angry i am new here

Comment: There is no such a code in your question.

Comment: error:Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='homeCenterDiv']/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/a"}
  (Session info: chrome=90.0.4430.212)

Comment: Does this element inside the site, not on the login page?

Comment: Inside the site

Comment: Sure, so you should again add the expected condition as previously before accessing it. You can simply put a sleep(5), but this is not a correct way to do this.
You should also correct your selector, it must be much shorter.